# Изменение заголовков в зависимости от выбранного select

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть форма по расчету фундамента.
В ней есть select с выбором Ленточный фундамент или Плиточный.

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе плиточного в других полях формы значения label менялись на Длина плиты и т.д.?

```
<script lang="JavaScript">
function calculator(form) {
var sel = document.getElementById("types"); // Получаем наш список
var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; // Получаем значение выделенного элемента.
L = eval(form.L.value);
s = eval(form.s.value);
h = eval(form.h.value);
if (val == 1) {

V = L*s*h;
V = V.toFixed(0);

M = V*130;
M = M.toFixed(2);

form.V.value = V;
form.M.value = M;
}

if (val == 2) {

V = L*s*h*1.04;
//V = b*104/100;
V = V.toFixed(2);

M = V*130;
M = M.toFixed(2);

form.V.value = V;
form.M.value = M;
}

}

</script>

<form>
<div class="former">
<label>Выберите тип фундамента</label>
    <select id="types">
        <option value="1">Ленточный фундамент</option>
        <option value="2">Плиточный фундамент</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="former">
<label>Длина ленты (L), м:</label>
 <input type="text" name="L" onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,'');" onkeyup="var n=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,''); if(n!=this.value) this.value=n;">
</div>
<div class="former">
<label>Ширина ленты (s), м:</label>
 <input type="text" name="s" onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,'');" onkeyup="var n=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,''); if(n!=this.value) this.value=n;">
</div>
<div class="former">
<label>Высота ленты (h), м:</label>
 <input type="text" name="h" onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,'');" onkeyup="var n=this.value.replace(/([^0-9])/g,''); if(n!=this.value) this.value=n;">
</div>
<div class="former">
<label>Диаметр арматуры:</label>
 <select id="diametr">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Рассчитать" onclick="calculator(this.form)">

<input type="reset" value="Сброс"><br>
<div class="former">
<label>Объем ленты (V) м<sup>3</sup>:</label> <input type="text" name="V"> 
</div>
<div class="former">
<label>Общий вес арматуры на ленту (M) кг.:</label> <input type="text" name="M"> 
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто все, оберни в спаны ключевые слова в label'ах, потом там, где ты получаешь список в скрипте, выбери нужный тип, и по этому типу изменяй содержимое спанов в label'ах.
Есть уйма решений такой банальной задачи.